# How to pop out list items outside div on hover, with overflow-y enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a mac os like effect on a list, such that the size of list items expand on hover. 
 Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chirag2796/Lgep1bu6/1/)
The problem is that i cannot make the items pop outside as a horizontal scrollbar appears. I cannot set the parent to `overflow: visible` because the verticle height is to be of fixed value and must be scrollable. So the effect of list items popping out on hover with verticle scrolling enabled is desired. No horizontal scrollbar is needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
li {
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
        background: #d00;
        display: block;
       
        text-align:center; /* Make Text Centered */
        padding:5px 0px;  /* ADD PADDING to TOP AND BOTTOM */
        /* ADD TRANSITION */
       transition:transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
        
    }

    li:hover {
       
        transform: scale(1.4);
       
    }
```

```html
<!--- ADD overflow-x:hidden; to hide horizontal scroll bar --->
<div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

Comment: dosen't work, overflow-x and overflow-y are tied together, if you set one other becomes overflow: auto automatically, that's the problem.Also text aligning and padding are not required.